# Sending image through intent

Tags: android, gridview

i wrote a program in which my images are read from sdcard and shown in as a gridview and when clicked on any image on the gridview , bigger image opens in another activity , i have also added a share button to share my image to different applications example whatsapp , so when i click on share , a chooser popsup and i also reach safely inside whatsapp where i select a user but when i select a user my image is not shown , below is the picture of the screen after i select a user

[image]

My code for the above

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Activity _activity;
private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
Intent intent, chooser;

// constructor
public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
    this._activity = activity;
    this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._imagePaths.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {
    TouchImageView imgDisplay;
    final Button btnClose, btnShare;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_imag,
            container, false);

    imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
    btnClose = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
    btnShare = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnShare);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position),
            options);
    imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri imageuri = Uri.parse("file://sdcard//Pictures//raw "
                    + _imagePaths);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageuri);
            chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via....");
            container.getContext().startActivity(chooser);

        }
    });

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

    return viewLayout;
}
```

i need to know where i am going wrong and please give suggestions
thanking you

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), image);
    File f = new File(getExternalCacheDir() + "/image.png");
    try {
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share From : XYZ");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image using"));
```

Comment: sir , i guess i cannot use getResources and hardcoded imagefile when i m reading images from sdcard , if i m wrong correct me

Comment: Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
screenshotUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(selectedImagePath)); sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg"); sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a "White space" in the Image Uri creation of yours :

```
Uri imageuri = Uri.parse("file://sdcard//Pictures//raw "
                + _imagePaths);
```

A space after the "raw"

Comment: i removed the white space still getting the same sir

Comment: @arjunnarahari Can you please check the image path by debugging, whether it is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(YourImage's uri here);
                whatsappIntent.setType("image/jpg"); 
                whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); 
    whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

    try {
        activity.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
    }
```

Comment: still getting the same result sir , sir i wanted to ask if my images uri is correct or not, and if container.startActivity which i have specified is right or not , because i was getting error in startActivity , if i remove container.getContext() , it says i need to create a startActivity method